# Taylor series third order approximation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, hessian-matrix

There has been this question that had been bothering me for a while and I could not find a satisfying answer on the internet or any of the books even though it is not very complex.

i) Its because if I have to find a third order polynomium approximation using taylor series for a 2 variable function, then is it correct to write that the third term will look something like this,

$$ ... + \frac{1}{3!}[f_{xxx}(x_0,y_0)(x-a)^3 + 6f_{xxy}(x_0,y_0)(x-a)(y-b)+f_{yyy}(x_0,y_0)(y-b)^3] + ....   $$

I was a bit unsure about the middle part.

ii) About the hessian matrix, how would I write a hessian matrix if I have to make one for a third order like the one above. I know that for second order it looks like,

$$H_f(x,y) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
f_{xx} & f_{xy} \\
f_{yx} & f_{yy}
\end{array}\right)$$

Thank You :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i) Looks like you want:
$\frac{1}{6} \left(3 (x-a)^2 (y-b) f_{\text{xxy}}\left(x_0,y_0\right)+3 (x-a) (y-b)^2 f_{\text{xyy}}\left(x_0,y_0\right)+(x-a)^3
   f_{\text{xxx}}\left(x_0,y_0\right)+(y-b)^3 f_{\text{yyy}}\left(x_0,y_0\right)\right)$

ii)
There's no third order "hessian matrix"

1st order derivative -> 2D vector

2nd order derivative -> 2x2 symmetric matrix

3rd order derivative -> 2x2x2 symmetric tensor.

Check wiki [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions).

Answer (score 0):

The third order term (it can be genralized to any order term) of the multivariable Taylor series of $f(\mathbf x):\mathbf R^n\to\mathbf R$ around $\mathbf a=(a,b,...)$ is
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{3!}((\mathbf x-\mathbf a)\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla|_{\mathbf a})^3f(\mathbf x)&\overset{\text{in }\mathbf R^2}{=}\frac{1}{3!}((x-a)\partial_x|_{\mathbf a}+(y-b)\partial_y|_{\mathbf a})^3f(x,y)\\
&\ \ =\frac{1}{3!}((x-a)^3\partial_{xxx}|_{\mathbf a}+3(x-a)^2(y-b)\partial_{xxy}|_{\mathbf a}\\
&\hspace{1.5cm}+3(x-a)(y-b)^2\partial_{xyy}|_{\mathbf a}+(y-b)^3\partial_{yyy}|_{\mathbf a})f(x,y)\\
&\ \ = \frac{1}{3!}[(x-a)^3f_{xxx}(a,b)+3(x-a)^2(y-b)f_{xxy}(a,b)\\
&\hspace{1.5cm}+3(x-a)(y-b)^2f_{xyy}(a,b)+(y-b)^3f_{yyy}(a,b)]
\end{aligned}
$$
or in matrix language, though in your case it is a $2\times 2\times 2$ tensor, I found it could be expressed as (example in $\mathbf R^2$)
$$
\frac{1}{3!}(x-a,y-b)\begin{pmatrix}
(\mathbf{x-a})\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla f_{xx}(\mathbf a) & (\mathbf{x-a})\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla f_{xy}(\mathbf a)\\
(\mathbf{x-a})\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla f_{yx}(\mathbf a) & (\mathbf{x-a})\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla f_{xx}(\mathbf a)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x-a\\
y-b
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Using Schwarz theorem ($f_{xy}=f_{yx}$) you can get to your expression.